# css min-height property not working in Mozilla or ie7

Tags: css, firefox, internet-explorer-7

I tried setting min-height property of  `<td style="min-height:500px"></td>`

Works fine on ie8, but not on IE7 or Mozilla 3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit: sorry, i misunderstood that question at first.

just use `height:500px`, as height is interpreted as minimum height on table cells anyway.

Comment: oops that was simple.... did that before .. :p :D Thanks for reminding .. :)
For Div cellls min-height can be set in the folllowing way.(this one too works fine) 
< div style =" width:100%; background:url(images/bg1.jpg) repeat; background-position:center;min-height:574px ; height:auto !important; height:574px; " align="center" > < / div >